# Is there an ORM out there that supports ESE?

Tags: .net, orm, extensible-storage-engine

Well, [I started](https://github.com/SamSaffron/simplestorageengine/tree/master) writing a managed ORM for [ESE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684493(VS.85).aspx) based on the [ESE interop](http://www.codeplex.com/ManagedEsent) project.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any other ORMs out there that support ESE?

Answer (score 2):

[Well, I did that :-)](http://const.me/source-code/esent-serialization/)

Comment: Is your ESENT Serialization Class Library open source?

Comment: @ChrisWeber, not currently. However, it's free even for commercial use, and the documentation is really good. If not having tha source code is a showstopper that prevents you from using the library, please drop me a line to soonts[at]live.com, and we'll duscuss that.